# Converting date in multiple formats to a new column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a big table with about 5 million rows in it.

Table:

```
ID (bigint), TRANS_DATE (TEXT)
```

Example:

`04/05/12 11:30`  and some rows will have it like `2012/22/05 14:50`

I created a new column `Date` which I need to set `date = STR_TO_DATE(TRANS_DATE , "????")`

What should I add in the `STR_TO_DATE` format to change it to the correct database date format?

Comment: `04/05/12` is `mm/dd/yy` or `yy/dd/mm` or `dd/mm/yy`?

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: @hjpotter92 its dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
date = STR_TO_DATE(TRANS_DATE ,
                   (case when len(trans_date) = 14 then '%d/%m/%y %h:%i'
                         else '%y/%m/%d %h:%i'
                    end)
                   )
```